# mkdir not working after rmdir in IE

Tags: php

I am having a strange issue with mkdir in IE9.

I seem to be able to check and create folders using

```
$temp_main_folder = session_id();
if(!is_dir($temp_main_folder)){ 
    mkdir($temp_main_folder . "/", 0755);
}
```

and remove a folder and all files inside the folder using unlink and rmdir.

This works every time with Firefox, Chrome, Safari. The issue is that the first time I run mkdir in IE it works. And the first time I run the rmdir in IE it works. However the next time I try to run mkdir in IE nothing happens. There are no error and I can see the folder being removed. I have to restart IE to get it to work again.

I am running Windows with Apache 2 webserver.

Comment: php is server side, browser is irelevant.

Comment: Yeah I know but its strange behavior that it only occurs when I am using IE

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can't effect php, as its server side..

The only effect browser can make can be decided by looking at the  `session_id()` function..

A wild guess probably ie is not sending cookies that are required to get session id..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all but the problem was that IE was caching the mkdir request so when I checked to see if the folder existed, IE still thought it did!

Comment: you mean caching the display of the directory structure? A browser cant cache a php function

Comment: OK well whatever it was as soon as I added header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); it worked